# Using Python 3 to strip invalid UTF-8 characters from file before loading to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, utf-8

I am working on a Python 3 script to upload a large number of CSV files to a MySQL database.

All of the csv files are supposed to be encoded as UTF-8, and my string fields in MySQL are type utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I'm using LOAD DATA INFILE but on at least one file so far I am getting an "Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string"

I have managed to isolate the problem row, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically identify and remove the bad characters.  I'm also not sure if the bad characters are interspersed with valid Arabic 
Characters (I think that is what they are) or if the Arabic characters are showing up as a result of the line being corrupt.  (I suspect the latter but really don't know).

In short, I'm trying to figure out how to programicallyt get this line into a form that it can be loaded in MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE.

I found a Stack Overflow answer that suggested using

`bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')`

but this does not seem to work.  As you can see below the exact same thing comes out as goes into the suggested transform.

```
with open('./badline.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    print(line)
    line2 = bytes(l, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    print(line2)
    print(line==line2)
```

Output

```
50172961,"THERAVANCE INC","901 جينوا ب ينوا بوليفار س ينوا باوث فرنسوليفار س ينوا بوليفار سيسكو كالاوث فرنس ينوا بوليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنس ينوا بليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالفورنيا 94080","US","",9,33431,"THERAVANCE INC",27623584,"THERAVANCE",1,"COMPANY",3531336,"THERAVANCE INC",2

50172961,"THERAVANCE INC","901 جينوا ب ينوا بوليفار س ينوا باوث فرنسوليفار س ينوا بوليفار سيسكو كالاوث فرنس ينوا بوليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنس ينوا بليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسليفار سيفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالاوث فرنسفورنيا 94064A;سكو كالفورنيا 94080","US","",9,33431,"THERAVANCE INC",27623584,"THERAVANCE",1,"COMPANY",3531336,"THERAVANCE INC",2

True
```

I've also provided the binary version below in case it is helpful

```
with open('./badline.txt', 'rb') as f:
    l = f.readline()
    print(l)
```

Output

```
b'50172961,"THERAVANCE INC","901 \xd8\xac\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94064A;\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3 \xd9\x8a\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xf2\x80\x99\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94064A;\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3\xf2\x80\x99\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xb3\xd9\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94064A;\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3\xf2\x80\x99\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94064A;\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd8\xab \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd8\xb3\xf2\x80\x99\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94064A;\xd8\xb3\xd9\x83\xd9\x88 \xd9\x83\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xf2\x80\x99\x8a\xd9\x81\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7 94080","US","",9,33431,"THERAVANCE INC",27623584,"THERAVANCE",1,"COMPANY",3531336,"THERAVANCE INC",2\r\n'
```

How can I either strip out the bad characters or identify the whole field as being bad?

*Note: the data included in the above examples is public*

Comment: write regex to accept only alphanumeric and other characters you want to include

Comment: The character before `94080` looks "bad".  The rest is Arabic or English. The rest looks OK.  GIGO.

Comment: My suspicion is that the problem is with the connection encoding. If it is still three-byte utf8, then a four-byte character would be silently cropped and become an invalid symbol at the moment of insertion into the field.

Comment: The problematic four-byte character is usually an emoji.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open(path_to_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    l = f.readline()
    print(l)
    new_l = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9#!,\"]+", " ", str(l))  # if you want to eleiminate arabic characters and all other characters which are not in regex
    print(new_l)
```

but Arabic characters are kind of language so I think if you can you should include it by using your own code or by replacing regex as

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9#!,\"[\u0627-\u064a]]+", " ", str(l))  # [\u0627-\u064a] will include your arabic characters
```

Comment: Thanks Gahan.  I have no issues with the Arabic characters, just the ones that aren't valid UTF-8.  It looks like the above will match the Arabic characters plus the standard alphanumerics, but is there shorthand in Python Regex to match all valid UTF-8 characters.  I found some in other questions, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: then, first of all, you need to check in which character set you are storing your content in text file.